# If in cache, use cached version, otherwise GET new JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

After some advice/guidance in regards to the end user performance.

Have put together a small client side 'person search' which is sourcing its data from a JSON file. The issue I am having is that the server which is compiling the JSON for use is old/slow (non for profit community group). As a result, users are having to wait between 3-6 seconds before they are able to interact with the page. I know there can be efficiencies made with how I make the request for the JSON data, but I am still very much new to javascript. The JSON is being compiled as:

```
print(JSON.stringify(datarecord));
```

This is how I am currently requesting the JSON file, and then using...

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "linktojson.json", false);
request.send(null);
var a = JSON.parse(request.responseText);


$(document).ready(function() {    
// Javascript things here
console.log(a);
}
```

I suspect as a result, every time the user accesses the page, a request is made. Then the JSON is compiled (slowly) and then the page is ready for use.

I have been looking at trying to store the JSON data in the users cache, so that way the JSON data only needs to be obtained once per session, however the load time still appears slow.

This is how I have updated my code.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "linktojson.json", false);
request.send(null);
localStorage.setItem("request",(request));

$(document).ready(function() {

var jsonString = localStorage.getItem("request");
var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.log(retrievedObject);
// Javascript things here
}
```

I have also been able to confirm that the bottleneck is occurring at the JSON request point to the server. I tested this by saving a copy of the JSON produced, then using this 'static' JSON file instead, and the page will render in under a second.

Then went further again, and used the following JSON file (28K records) and the page still rendered quickly.

LINK: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prust/wikipedia-movie-data/master/movies.json

Sorry if this is a little long winded. I wanted to help describe the problem as best as possible.

Comment: What do you exepct that `localStorage.setItem("request", JSON.stringify(request));` would do?

Comment: Should just be  localStorage.setItem("request", (request)); ?

Comment: May question is what you expect that this line of code does? The code at `This is how I have updated my code.` does not prevent your website from doing the request to the server.

Comment: I have updated my original post, as it didnt make sense to try and stringify json data which was already a string. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: But `request` is the request object and not the contents of the response `request.responseText`. And how do you expect that it should reduce the load from the server? And you still do the request in a synchronous way, so it is still blocking? Btw. doing synchronous blocking requests is deprected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to utilize caching, you have to check that cache first before you do a request. Otherwise, it won't make much sense.

And doing synchronous blocking requests is deprecated, and you should also switch over to use `fetch` if possible instead of `XMLHttpRequest`.

A function that first checks if the data is in the catch before doing the request could look like this:

```
async function getData() {
   let data = localStorage.getItem('request')
   // check if data is in cache
   if( data === null ) {
      // if it is not in cache then request it
      const response = await fetch('linktojson.json')

      // parse the json response
      data = await response.json()
      
      // store the data in the cache
      localStorage.setItem('request', JSON.stringify(data));
   } else {
      // if it exists then parse it
      data = JSON.parse(data)
   }

   // return the data
   return data
}
```

You could then do something like this:

```
getData()
.then(data => {
   // ensure DOM is ready
   $(() => {
      console.log('do something with data', data)
   })
})
.catch(err => {
   console.log('error occured')
})
```

The code could also be written like that:

```
function waitForDomReady() {
   return new Promise(resolve => $(resolve))
}

async function run() {
   try {
       let data = await getData();
       
       await waitForDomReady();
       
       console.log('do something with data', data)
   } catch (err) {
       console.log('error occured')
   }
}


run()
```